# Reading an image to FPGA from PC and Back

Tags: image, vhdl, verilog, fpga, hdl

I need to read a small image (tif format) from PC to FPGA kit (ALTERA DE2-70) for processing, then write it back to PC. I have no idea how to do it in Verilog?

Can it be done in C? if so, how can I combine my C/HDL code to work together?

Thank you!

Comment: Which of the many connectors on the DE2-70 do you plan to send the image through?  You will probably find it a lot easier to decompress the image on the PC, send raw pixel values to the FPGA, and get raw pixel values back.  And, you will need PC software and FPGA logic working together to do the transfer, it's theoretically possible to use existing file server software on the PC side but that would make your FPGA logic much much more complex.

Comment: I was thinking of using the usb port as the sole connector for the two way transfer! I need the picture to attempt a hardware OCR. I have the same dataset in BMP format, so no worries about getting raw pixels. What software do you suggest to initiate transfer and back to the PC? How will the FPGA know that a transfer has begun and store the pixels data and where?

Comment: Well, if you mean the USB debug/programming port, then Altera provides a UART-via-JTAG component you can place into your design.  You'd then need to use the terminal window in Quartus to send and receive data... and there will be control signals on the component to tell your FPGA logic when a new byte arrives and for your FPGA logic to tell the port to send a byte.  If you meant the USB-B connector, you'd need USB client logic in the FPGA to respond to enumeration with device descriptors and do data transfers.

Comment: The debug USB option will be easier, but slower.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I will start working directly after Christmas day, for I have exams now, GRE and others :) I shall post my progress or any problems here if I encounter any!

Comment: Update: I have received the kit today, My friend suggested to use the onbard SD Card slot, that is, load the photos from PC to SDRAM card by a simple copy/paste, plugin the card in the SD card slot, and use the NIOS II or Altera modules to copy the images to the RAM, what do you think? Isn't this simpler?

Answer (score 5):

a few mounts ago i were having the same problem, but i wanted to send and receive a real time image. back then i was researching and the best (fast an chip) solution that i find was the XEM6001 of opalkelly. http://www.opalkelly.com/products/xem6001/
specify controller (Cypress cy68013a) that handle all the communication on a 36 MBytes/second between the PC and FPGA in USB.
and API (Application Programmer's Interface) in C, C++, C#, Ruby, Python, and Java. the price 200$. ---odsa---