# How to feed an image file into an FPGA?

Tags: image-processing, fpga

I am trying to get an image into an fpga board and from somewhere I learned that it can be done by converting it into an hex file. But, the next thing to ponder over is if at all I have it in my fpga will it be useful in its form for my project.

Since I am trying to do some column wise and row wise filtering followed by downsampling ?

Comment: This question is far too lacking in detail to be answerable. "fpga board" could be anything, and loading it with data is unlikely to be a software problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an image to FPGA from PC and Back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478083/reading-an-image-to-fpga-from-pc-and-back)

Comment: I am working on implementation of image fusion algorithm using wavelet transform on FPGA (I haven't yet decided which board to use , since I haven't done the timing analysis of the architecture that I am planning to implement). As for now the type and specification is not a concern. Only motive for now is to get an image file into FPGA chip (present on any FPGA board for now) such that, the data obtained in it is directly susceptible to column and row wise filtering and downsampling. I am unable to understand, how some image data undergoes processing into an FPGA.  ?